# Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'

Tags: python, django, ibm-cloud

I am trying to push my application on bluemix using Git as well as Bluemix pipeline. I got error in both the cases in the build stage.
To be more specific ,  **I am using Python 2.7 on Windows OS.**

The error is as mentioned below -

```html
You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
$ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
```

My requirements.txt file :

```html
Django==1.6.5
pygal==1.5.0
pymongo==2.8.0
cloudant==2.0.0a1
twitter==1.14.3
dj-database-url==0.3.0
django-cors-headers==1.0.0
xlwt==1.0.0
requests==2.7.0
```

Will disabling collectstatic help me solve this issue? and if yes, how can i do it on windows?

Comment: You haven't said what the error is.

Comment: The error is 'BuildpackCompileFailed' . I am not able to push my application from local machine to Production

Comment: Can you provide the `cf push` command you are using? Are you specify a buildpack? In addition, can you provide the output of `cf logs --recent` ?

Comment: @HobertBushIII I am using `cf push -f manifest.yml` for pushing the application. The logs for 'cf logs --recent' is too long to add here .But i have added a section `------> Buildpack version 1.1.2
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5`

Comment: Thank you. Since you are you using a manifest.yml file, can you post it as well?

Comment: @HobertBushIII manifest file : `applications:
- name: twhispermanager
  memory: 512M
  command: python manage.py runserver
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack#v1.1.2
  path: .`

Comment: Thankyou all.. I have been able to solve this issue.. I suspect it was because of an old buildpack version i was using.. Using the newer buildpack helped me push my application on bluemix.